# ORing filters together in Pony ORM

Tags: python, ponyorm

I would like to dynamically build a query using [Pony](https://ponyorm.com/), but I would
like to combine the filters with `OR` instead of with `AND`.  That is,
I want to do something like this:

```
keywords = ['gizmo', 'gadget']
query = select(w for w in Widget)
for kw in keywords:
  query = query.filter(lambda w: kw in w.name)

for item in query:
  print(item)
```

The problem with the above, of course, is that it will produce a query
like:

```
SELECT "w"."id", "w"."name"
FROM "Widget" "w"
WHERE "w"."name" LIKE '%gizmo%'
  AND "w"."name" LIKE '%gadget%'
```

Whereas I want:

```
SELECT "w"."id", "w"."name"
FROM "Widget" "w"
WHERE "w"."name" LIKE '%gizmo%'
  OR "w"."name" LIKE '%gadget%'
```

Is there any way to get there?

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you can't use filters with or. Someday we'll implement this.

I can give you some workaround with strings.

In Pony you can use string version of generators or filters. Like

```
select('w for w in Widget')
```

It might be useful if you use some expression that Pony can't decompile. For example

```
select('s for s in Student if a < s.age < b')
```

So in your case you can do it like

```
q = select(w for w in Widget)
q = q.filter(' or '.join('keywords[%d] in w.name' % i for i in range(len(keywords))))
```

I use `for i in range` not `for kw in keywords` to avoid python injections, because this code will be evaluated.